No goal checker was specified
I'm trying to setup Nav2 for Humble but everytime I send a goal I get the following error:
[INFO] [1722361205.771845530] [controller_server]: Received a goal, begin computing control effort.
[WARN] [1722361205.771907547] [controller_server]: No goal checker was specified in parameter 'current_goal_checker'. Server will use only plugin loaded general_goal_checker . This warning will appear once.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Here is what my controller_server params look like, they are taken from nav2 Humble github.
controller_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    controller_frequency: 20.0
    min_x_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    min_y_velocity_threshold: 0.5
    min_theta_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    failure_tolerance: 0.3
    progress_checker_plugin: "progress_checker"
    goal_checker_plugins: ["general_goal_checker"]
    controller_plugins: ["FollowPath"]
    # Progress checker parameters
    progress_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker"
      required_movement_radius: 0.5
      movement_time_allowance: 10.0

    general_goal_checker:
      stateful: True
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.25
    # DWB parameters
    FollowPath:
      plugin: "dwb_core::DWBLocalPlanner"
      debug_trajectory_details: True
      min_vel_x: 0.0
      min_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_x: 0.26
      max_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_theta: 1.0
      min_speed_xy: 0.0
      max_speed_xy: 0.26
      min_speed_theta: 0.0
      # Add high threshold velocity for turtlebot 3 issue.
      # https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations/issues/75
      acc_lim_x: 2.5
      acc_lim_y: 0.0
      acc_lim_theta: 3.2
      decel_lim_x: -2.5
      decel_lim_y: 0.0
      decel_lim_theta: -3.2
      vx_samples: 20
      vy_samples: 5
      vtheta_samples: 20
      sim_time: 1.7
      linear_granularity: 0.05
      angular_granularity: 0.025
      transform_tolerance: 0.2
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      trans_stopped_velocity: 0.25
      short_circuit_trajectory_evaluation: True
      stateful: True
      critics: ["RotateToGoal", "Oscillation", "BaseObstacle", "GoalAlign", "PathAlign", "PathDist", "GoalDist"]
      BaseObstacle.scale: 0.02
      PathAlign.scale: 32.0
      PathAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      GoalAlign.scale: 24.0
      GoalAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      PathDist.scale: 32.0
      GoalDist.scale: 24.0
      RotateToGoal.scale: 32.0
      RotateToGoal.slowing_factor: 5.0
      RotateToGoal.lookahead_time: -1.0

This is a more verbose output. Error is after "Path end point..."
[INFO] [1722367293.982505733] [controller_server]: Received a goal, begin computing control effort.
[DEBUG] [1722367293.982482334] [rcl]: Service take request succeeded: true
[DEBUG] [1722367293.982528176] [controller_server]: Selected controller: FollowPath.
[WARN] [1722367293.982615471] [controller_server]: No goal checker was specified in parameter 'current_goal_checker'. Server will use only plugin loaded general_goal_checker . This warning will appear once.
[DEBUG] [1722367293.982648793] [controller_server]: Providing path to the controller FollowPath
[DEBUG] [1722367293.985320245] [rcl]: Subscription taking message
[DEBUG] [1722367293.985906138] [rcl]: Subscription take succeeded: true
[DEBUG] [1722367293.987424069] [rcl]: Subscription taking message
[DEBUG] [1722367293.987559683] [rcl]: Subscription take succeeded: true
[DEBUG] [1722367293.988405086] [rcl]: Subscription taking message
[DEBUG] [1722367293.988482097] [rcl]: Subscription take succeeded: true
[DEBUG] [1722367293.988531262] [rcl]: Subscription taking message
[DEBUG] [1722367293.988610804] [rcl]: Subscription take succeeded: true
[DEBUG] [1722367293.988797023] [rcl]: Subscription taking message
[DEBUG] [1722367293.988832937] [rcl]: Subscription take succeeded: true
[DEBUG] [1722367293.990918153] [rcl]: Subscription taking message
[DEBUG] [1722367293.990969807] [rcl]: Subscription take succeeded: true
[DEBUG] [1722367293.994588623] [rcl]: Subscription taking message
[DEBUG] [1722367293.994644770] [rcl]: Subscription take succeeded: true
[DEBUG] [1722367294.003165560] [controller_server]: Path end point is (-2.95, -3.33)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)


The logged error is just telling you that its using the default, single algorithm given, that's expected when you don't specify a goal checker / progress checker but only have one defined.
The crash needs a traceback to know what is causing it. See our tutorial: https://docs.nav2.org/tutorials/docs/get_backtrace.html and provide the trace.

I currently get this error:
[ERROR] [1722503680.166837361] [controller_server]: Couldn't load critics! Caught exception: No critics defined for FollowPath
[ERROR] [1722503680.177688511] [controller_server]: Caught exception in callback for transition 10
[ERROR] [1722503680.177752961] [controller_server]: Original error: No critics defined for FollowPath
[WARN] [1722503680.177799791] [controller_server]: Error occurred while doing error handling.
[FATAL] [1722503680.177830889] [controller_server]: Lifecycle node controller_server does not have error state implemented
[WARN] [1722503681.356095639] [rcl_lifecycle]: No transition matching 3 found for current state unconfigured
[ERROR] [1722503681.356138727] [controller_server]: Unable to start transition 3 from current state unconfigured: Transition is not registered., at ./src/rcl_lifecycle.c:355

With params taken for GitHub humble branch
controller_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    controller_frequency: 20.0
    min_x_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    min_y_velocity_threshold: 0.5
    min_theta_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    failure_tolerance: 0.3
    progress_checker_plugin: "progress_checker"
    goal_checker_plugins: ["general_goal_checker"]
    controller_plugins: ["FollowPath"]
    # Progress checker parameters
    progress_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker"
      required_movement_radius: 0.5
      movement_time_allowance: 10.0
    general_goal_checker:
      stateful: True
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.25
    # DWB parameters
    FollowPath:
      plugin: "dwb_core::DWBLocalPlanner"
      debug_trajectory_details: True
      min_vel_x: 0.0
      min_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_x: 0.26
      max_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_theta: 1.0
      min_speed_xy: 0.0
      max_speed_xy: 0.26
      min_speed_theta: 0.0
      # Add high threshold velocity for turtlebot 3 issue.
      # https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations/issues/75
      acc_lim_x: 2.5
      acc_lim_y: 0.0
      acc_lim_theta: 3.2
      decel_lim_x: -2.5
      decel_lim_y: 0.0
      decel_lim_theta: -3.2
      vx_samples: 20
      vy_samples: 5
      vtheta_samples: 20
      sim_time: 1.7
      linear_granularity: 0.05
      angular_granularity: 0.025
      transform_tolerance: 0.2
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      trans_stopped_velocity: 0.25
      short_circuit_trajectory_evaluation: True
      stateful: True
      critics: ["RotateToGoal", "Oscillation", "BaseObstacle", "GoalAlign", "PathAlign", "PathDist", "GoalDist"]
      BaseObstacle.scale: 0.02
      PathAlign.scale: 32.0
      PathAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      GoalAlign.scale: 24.0
      GoalAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      PathDist.scale: 32.0
      GoalDist.scale: 24.0
      RotateToGoal.scale: 32.0
      RotateToGoal.slowing_factor: 5.0
      RotateToGoal.lookahead_time: -1.0


please edit your question instead of having the question as an answer
